# If $\tan\theta_1=a$ and $\tan\theta_2=1/a$, then what is the relation between $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$?

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

Let $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ be two angles such that $\tan\theta_1=a$ and $\tan\theta_2=1/a$, with $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

From the context of the problem that has raised my doubts, I think that $90 ^{\circ}- \theta_2= \theta_1$. Would this be true? How could it be proved?

Comment: How have you reached your conclusion? Could you please edit your question to include the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\tan\theta_1\tan\theta_2=1$$ or
$$\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2-\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2=0$$ or
$$\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)=0$$ or
$$\theta_1+\theta_2=90^{\circ}+180^{\circ}k,$$ where $k$ is an integer number.

Answer (score 3):

A picture is worth a thousand equations:

[image]

Comment: It's given that $a$ is a real number.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\tan\theta_1=\frac{1}{\tan{\theta_2}}\\
\frac{\sin\theta_1}{\cos\theta_1}=\frac{\cos{\theta_2}}{\sin{\theta2}}\\
\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2=\cos\theta_1\cos{\theta_2}\\
\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)-\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)=\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)+\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)\\
cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)=0
$$
This means that $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ must add up to an odd multiple of $\frac\pi2$.
$$
\theta_1+\theta_2=\frac\pi2+k\pi
$$
where $k \in \Bbb{Z}$